# jquery ui autocomplete doesn't work with jquery version 3.2.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Hi I am using jquery version 3.2.1 in our projects and now i need to use jquery ui autocomplete which contains version 1.12.4. Due to this our position of autocomplete change(top and left position). For this I just found a temporary solution.I calculate position dynamically through jquery and set position through jquery. But I am not sure I can get a problem in any other functionality in future. SO is there any other solution for this that works fine in all situation. The autocomplete i am using is [this](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

The file in autocomplete  are:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

And I need to use

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
```

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Did you include jQuery Ui ? If not then include it and try..

Comment: yes i have included it it just not working properly for version 3.2.1

Comment: Add  your code here

Answer (score 0):

Check this code it's working. [Reference](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's also not working for me in the development script. We have newer jquery that loads over the older jquery version. And UI don't work with newer jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for my input autocomplet city,

With the version 3, Jquery autocomplet work differently. You need to put your data before {} :

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete(availableTags{
      // others options
    });
  } );
</script>
```